# std::underlying_type support in clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm, std, clang++

I assume C++ Compound type alterations support should be enabled in `clang++` by `-std=c++11` switch. But I'm unable to compile this code using clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class A {a,b,c};
enum B : short {x,y,z};

int main() {

  typedef std::underlying_type<A>::type A_under;   // int
  typedef std::underlying_type<B>::type B_under;   // short

  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "typedefs of int:" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "A_under: " << std::is_same<int,A_under>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "B_under: " << std::is_same<int,B_under>::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
$ clang++ underlyingtype.cpp -std=c++11
underlyingtype.cpp:10:16: error: no type named 'underlying_type' in namespace 'std'
  typedef std::underlying_type<A>::type A_under;   // int
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**Further information:**

```
lashgar@fengdu:~/code$ clang++ --version
clang version 3.8.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 1ad799453a2e54cfded555a03fd58dbd102c5f62) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git af5ff60200812e518c72a022fb4c66b9a5f0116a)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/lashgar/opt/llvm/bin
```

Comment: This is mostly a standard library issue, not a compiler issue. Which standard library implementation are you using? libstdc++, or libc++? And which version?

Comment: @hvd Thanks for the reply, how can I check this?

Comment: Inspecting the preprocessor output (`clang++ -std=c++11 -E yourfile.cc`) shows exactly which header files end up used. Typically, the paths of those files already indicates the implementation and version. For instance, `clang++ -E -xc++ - -std=c++11 <<< '#include <type_traits>'` on my system shows that it includes `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/type_traits`. This is the libstdc++ that comes with GCC 4.9.3. If your path doesn't already indicate it, look at the header file itself, they generally include info right at the start.

Comment: your libstdc++ version must be 4.6 or earlier, at least that's what I can reproduce on Wandbox.

Comment: This is OT, isn't it?

Comment: @black I don't believe this is off-topic, this should work with a compiler that support C++11 and the OP has provided a MCVE.

Comment: @hvd Thanks, this was the issue. I was using `libstdc++`. I switch the standard library to `libc++` and it works. I used this command: `clang++ underlyingtype.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`. Please post you comment as the answer so we mark this question answered.

Comment: In fairness @TemplateRex's comment actually provided the info on which versions work and which don't, so maybe that's a better candidate for a comment to be reposted as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to an [**online compiler with libstdc++ 4.6.4**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UQEzABHT43Cja8xf) that reproduces this error.

Just make sure to get the version of your Standard Library. libstdc++ 4.7 and higher or libc++ 3.0 and higher should work correctly.